# In Drupal, how do auto-list headlines from a news section on the homepage?

Tags: drupal

**Requirements:**

- Headlines also go to an RSS feed on the home page
- Needs to be a link below the listing to "View More News" (meaning it goes to the news section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) to create your list, and publish it as a block on the home page and as an RSS feed.

Comment: +1 Had that installed for weeks, looks like a huge pain to use. Know any basic how's that relate to what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Views can be overwhelming at first, but it's a hugely flexible and powerful tool. Views allows you to build database queries and output the results in a number of ways (table, list, RSS). Allow yourself some time to get to know it, you will not regret it. Make sure to install the Advanced Help module (http://drupal.org/project/advanced_help) along with it to reveal the documentation contained in the module. Once you wrap your head around Views, it will become a second nature and solving this problem will be easy.

Comment: (+2 total & selected as answer.) Thanks... I'll try the AdvHelp.mod and see what happens.